# I cannot update Kali Linu via apt-get, it's a fresh install

Tags: linux, debian, dns, aptitude

I installed Kali for the second time, since I tried to update to Sana.
And now I can't update. It looks like it's using kotnet.kuleuven.be:53 specifically, which is this University log-in for internet page.

This worked before, I can't figure this out...

```
root@kali:~# sudo aptitude update
Err http://http.kali.org kali Release.gpg
Could not resolve 'kotnet.kuleuven.be:53'
```

likewise for other repo

```
W: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/kali/Release.gpg: Could not resolve 'kotnet.kuleuven.be:53'
```

similarly for other repo

```
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: root@kali:~# sudo aptitude update
Err http://http.kali.org kali Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'kotnet.kuleuven.be:53'
Err http://security.kali.org kali/updates Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'kotnet.kuleuven.be:53'
W: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/kali/Release.gpg: Could not resolve 'kotnet.kuleuven.be:53'
W: Failed to fetch http://security.kali.org/kali-security/dists/kali/updates/Release.gpg: Could not resolve 'kotnet.kuleuven.be:53'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Comment: this is the terminal output ofcourse

Comment: Could you please post the content of your sources.list file? (`/etc/apt/sources.list`)

Comment: # Regular
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali main non-free contrib
deb http://security.kali.org/kali-security kali/updates main contrib non-free
# Source
deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali main non-free contrib
deb-src http://security.kali.org/kali-security kali/updates main contrib non-free

should be fine

Comment: The `sources.list` for Kali Sana would contain the keyword `sana` at several points. `deb http://http.kali.org/kali sana main non-free contrib
deb http://security.kali.org/kali-security/ sana/updates main contrib non-free` according to [Kali Linux 2.0 Release Notes](https://www.kali.org/releases/kali-linux-20-released/)

Comment: Yes but, it is not sana, It is normal kali. I used my usb installer which contains the previous version (before sana) and this works fine on other systems.

Comment: Does this problem persist throughout reboot?

Comment: Yes, I tried all sorts of different repo's and edited my resolv.conf (which I returned to normal values) but it persists.

Comment: this is my 'resolv.conf' content 'domain kotnet.kuleuven.be
search kotnet.kuleuven.be
nameserver 134.58.126.3
nameserver 134.58.127.1'

Comment: You could try to explicitly replace the mirror by replacing the `http://http.kali.org/kali` in your `sources.list`with some other official mirror. For example: `http://ftp.halifax.rwth-aachen.de/kali`. [Official mirrors](http://http.kali.org/README.mirrorlist)

Comment: same error, just with the new mirror

Comment: Can you ping some other websites by domain name? E.g. `ping google.com`? Looks like there is a problem resolving the IP of your nameserver after having read your previous comment. Can you ping the nameserver? (`ping kotnet.kuleuven.be`)

Comment: I can ping all websites, and there is no packet loss, all send, all received,even to kotnet

Comment: Also `http.kali.org`? Sounds strange to me that Kali can't resolve the server name to an IP but can ping it by its name.

Comment: All sites are pinged, no problem, there's something with that kotnet thing tough, it's just a page on this wlan connection which I have to log in to to have internet, but it also says its my domain en search

Answer (score 0):

The interesting error is: "Could not resolve 'kotnet.kuleuven.be:53"

Apparently this is your nameserver (Port 53 = DNS), but unfortunately he can't find it because he can't resolve the name without a nameserver... :)

I see two possible solutions:

1) Put the IP address of kotnet.kuleuven.be or another nameserver in `/etc/resolv.conf`

or

2) Add kotnet.kuleuven.be to `/etc/hosts`

Comment: This didn't work, I tried the two solutions...
It's strange tough, why specifically 53
and this never happened before, didn't do anything different,
I can (clearly) acces the web. Moreover, when I try to look up the IP, it says kotnet.kuleuven.be doesn't have one...

Comment: The proper nameservers are already in the resolv.conf